# How can I obtain a list of all files removed with make clean

Tags: cmake

CMake provides a global clean target for Unix Makefile projects. A list of files or directories that will be removed as a part of the global clean target can be retrieved by the `ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES` property:

```
get_property( FILES_TO_CLEAN DIRECTORY PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES )
message( "Clean: ${FILES_TO_CLEAN}" )
```

This list is incomplete as it only lists the files that are *additionally* removed.

Question:

How can I obtain a list of all files or folders which are removed as a part of the global clean target?

Comment: `find . | sort > before.txt; make clean; find . | sort > after.txt; comm -13 before.txt after.txt`?

Comment: @HardcoreHenry not what I had in mind but accepted :)
I was hoping to find some hints from CMake files, properties, etc

Comment: I figured as much, which is why I didn't post as an answer.  Thought I'd put it out there though.   Can't help you with CMake -- out of my area of expertise.